# How to pass query string parameters from one page and get in another in WP 7 using MVVM Light

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mvvm, navigation, mvvm-light

I am developing application in Windows Phone 7 in MVVM arhticeture.
I have never worked with MVVM Light. But today for sending querystring parameters from ViewModel of first Page  to another, I have searched google and found that I have to use MVVMLight.
But I cant find any tutorial or working sample. I have found one that it navigates from one  page to another, but without parameters.

**UPDATE**
How to change this solution that in can get parameters from OrderViewModel?
[code can be found here](http://hirenkhirsaria.blogspot.com/2012/04/windows-phone-7-using-page-navigation.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a concept called messaging. Read more on Geoff's Blog: [MVVM Light - Passing Params to Target ViewModel Before Navigating](http://geoffwebbercross.blogspot.com/2012/04/mvvm-light-passing-params-to-target.html).

Basically, you send a message of some type (represented by a C# class) and the target ViewModel registers itself as the recipient of that message. Once you broadcast the message, the other view model will be called.

Comment: It is ok. But it would be great if there was working solution for downloading. :(